# Dreamforce SFSE Speakers

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

Wondering who all from SFSE are speaking at Dreamforce 2014 and on what topics? I have 2 sessions - one for newbie developers and another one aimed at Salesforce1 mobile automation testing. Looking forward to hearing what other SFSE buddies are presenting on.

Answer (score 7):

Nice one Gaurav!

I've got one on using Knockout JS on the platform, and another on SFSE! :)

Answer (score 7):

I'll be there to talk about extending the capabilities of Wsdl2Apex. It will also be my first time attending Dreamforce as well.

For anyone in New Zealand, I'm giving a slightly different version of the talk in [Auckland on the 28th of August to the New Zealand Salesforce Developers Group](http://www.meetup.com/New-Zealand-Salesforce-Developer-Group/events/196446552/).

<strike>When talks start to appear in the agenda builder we should link to them from here.</strike>

[Using the Tooling API to Generate Apex SOAP Web Service Clients](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions#/session/a2q30000000guowAAA)

> Join us as we review the capabilities of the existing WSDL-to-Apex code generation feature, and explain how we built a tool to provide expanded features using the Tooling API. The resulting tool has greater support for more WSDL features, generates test cases and the associated mocks to maximize code coverage, and optionally includes HttpRequest versions of the callouts.
>
> Monday, 3:00 PM - 3:40 PM
> Moscone Center West
> 2005

Answer (score 6):

I'll be talking about geolocation in the devzone:

"Geolocation Fields in SOQL and Formulas: Tips & Tricks"

Wednesday, 5:30 PM - 6:00 PM

Moscone Center West, Mobile Theater

Comment: Want to share the session name? Search wasn't working for speaker names last I checked.

Comment: edited to add name + time, @ca_peterson

Answer (score 5):

I'll be doing 1-2 sessions at SF. One on integrating the Pebble watch with SF and another on developer best practices (tentative).

Answer (score 5):

I've got 2 sessions so far.

Development on Force.com which will cover use of Git, CI and other tools.

Writing effective validation rules

Answer (score 5):

I will be speaking at Dreamforce this year (yay!) about building a message queue type system using apex on the the force.com platform.

Answer (score 5):

One session on SOQL selectivity and using the new explain query pilot, "Faster SOQL? Yes, Please". Co-presenting with John Tan of salesforce's customer centric engineering team.

Answer (score 3):

I have one session with fellow force.com MVP Chris Lewis on Wednesday PM (4:45 I think) about "Clicks vs Code" - in which we will be presenting 3 scenarios and their click/code solutions and getting the audience to vote on their favourite route.

I'm also doing a Hands On Training session on Monday, on "Fast Track to Salesforce1 App Development" from 12:15 - 2:45.

I take it we will all be way too busy to even attempt a SFSE Meetup/pint at any point? Even if we just try to block in one hour at a public bar or something?

Comment: Have you seen [Dreamforce '14 - Let's Meet!](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/705/dreamforce-14-lets-meet).

Comment: ah, I had not! (though I have seen that picture before... at least once ;) ) I will check in with it now.

Comment: oh, right! Turns out I had seen that, because I had commented back in July!! Signed up now and looking forward to it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm keeping it simple. **Live-coding Call to Case using Twilio** with callback confirmation.

The best part is that it is like a game of telephone where the person calls a number, leaves a message, and the system calls back with what it thinks was said. If I ever link ten of these together, it could be hilarious to see what comes of it!