# Dreamforce 2018 SFSE Speakers

Tags: discussion

Dreamforce 2018 Speakers list is out, So how many from SFSE managed to get a Session or two on it. Similar questions have been asked in past so wondering what SFSE speakers offering in DF 18.

Src: [Dreamforce SFSE Speakers](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/717/dreamforce-sfse-speakers?rq=1)

Comment: Because of Stupid Reasons™, I will not be attending this year, but I do hope all the stuff will be cast on youtube or something, as there are many great sessions out there.

Comment: Its a shame that we won't be able to meet Sir @sfdcfox this DF, keeping fingers crossed for future.

Comment: I'm glad you posted this Pranay. I had wanted to congratulate the many members of our community that I recognized on the list and wanted to know if there were some that were presenting that I didn't because of their user names. Congrats to all who made the cut, was a huge list that submitted proposals! :)

Comment: Is there a specific official Salesforce url, where we can find all the list of topics along with the Speakers?

Comment: Sadly I'll have to wait for the videos of the sessions again this year.

Comment: @ArnoldJr., see https://success.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q3A00001XoCSUUA3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am doing ["Continuous Integration with Salesforce DX: Concepts and Connections"](https://success.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q3A00001XoCSUUA3#/session/a2q3A000001WVMwQAO). It'll be based on a talk I gave at PhillyForce earlier this year.

Comment: Sounds good! Can you add the session link here once it's available (I don't know if they're available yet, out of the loop!)?

Comment: I will! Mine is not yet posted but I believe it will be soon.

Answer (score 6):

My Theater session is up. It is on using the MetadataComponentDependency pilot to create a graph of an orgs "Happy Soup". You can then visualizse that graph in various ways to look for things like potential packages, disconnected code, where a particular field is used, ...

> ## [Understand your Org shape via visualization of Metadata Component Dependencies](https://success.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q3A00001XoCSUUA3#/session/a2q3A000001WWXOQA4)
>
> When moving to Salesforce DX unlocked packages you need a fast and easy way to identify the modules that make up a Salesforce org and how they are related to each other. This also applies when needing insight into how a specific field is used by other components.
>
> By using MetadataComponentDependency queries along with Gephi, an open-source visualization and exploration tool for graphs, we can rapidly untangle the dependencies via a range of layouts and metrics. These interactive visualizations aid developers in understanding the shape of a Salesforce org, leading to benefits as migrating Visualforce pages to Lightning components and identifying potential packages from complex metadata relationships.

The final examples will have labels on the nodes, but here is the general idea from a fresh scratch org where there are for custom objects. Two linked via a Master-Detail relationship and two via a lookup relationship.

[image]

Or a more complicated example with the Dreamhouse app:

[image]

Comment: Our sessions are at the same time. I really wanted to see this!

Comment: @DavidReed That's a pain. I had your session bookmarked. I see you're over at the Hilton.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to post here but I'm doing 4 sessions this year (two technical and two non-tech). Hope to see some of you at one of my sessions!

[1) Salesforce Meets Avengers - A Marvel API Integration](https://success.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q3A00001XoCSUUA3#/session/a2q3A000001WWGvQAO)

Wednesday, September 26, 9:30 AM - 9:50 AM
Moscone West, Valley Theater

Join in if you are curious about Salesforce mobile integrations, a Marvel fan or both!

[2) Demystifying Mobile-First eCommerce Sites with Commerce Cloud SFRA](https://success.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q3A00001XoCSUUA3#/session/a2q3A000001WWWuQAO)

Thursday, September 27, 10:30 AM - 10:50 AM
Moscone West, Developer Theater

Join in if you are a Commerce Cloud developer and want to explore why & how to migrate your app to SFRA

[3) Level Up Your Skills: Going from Good to Great as a Salesforce Developer](https://success.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q3A00001XoCSUUA3#/session/a2q3A000001WZmKQAW)

Wednesday, September 26, 2:30 PM - 2:50 PM
Moscone West, Valley Theater

A session by Pluralsight authors (Yours truly, David Liu, Dan Appleman & Don Robins) on various aspects of the Salesforce learning journey

[4) Salesforce MVPs: Tap Into This Network of Salesforce Expertise and Inspiration](https://success.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q3A00001XoCSUUA3#/session/a2q3A000001WZCnQAO)

Tuesday, September 25, 11:00 AM - 11:20 AM
Moscone West, Trailblazer Community Campfire

- A session to interact with MVPs, I'll be joined by fellow MVPs - Amber Boaz & Stacey Cogswell on this one!